# RTSP not playing when use public ip

Tags: android, swift, ip-camera

We have an app where we are showing live video using ip camera.

When camera + iPhone is on same network, we can see video using below link.

```
rtsp://admin:password@192.168.1.1/h264_stream
```

When we need to take live, we replace `192.168.1.1` with public ip we have, video is not coming in the app.

```
rtsp://admin:password@public_ip:8000/h264_stream
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Note : When we try to access camera using our public ip we have (in external app), it's working fine.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mcu.iVMS&hl=en

Any idea what we are missing? Like authentication required or any further setting is required?

Note : Camera is of [ezviz](https://www.ezvizlife.com/en) company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ezviz camera default port is 554, so you must activate port 554 on your router. Once that is done, use URL as below and we are done.

```
rtsp://admin:password@public_ip:554/h264_stream
```